# SVN not working and not able to update files

Tags: svn, yii

I have copied my working file to /var/www/html folder ...
but it does not able to update the **files through SVN** (i have installed SVN to connect with live test server)
**click this link to view image**

[working folder copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa6Wo.jpg)

---

really it shows green tick instead of clock symbol
    but when i tried to copy to /var/www/html/sameFolder beofre six months it seems that ok

Answer (score 0):

You should take **backup** of that file and delete from this svn folder.
then use **SVN Update** in this folder. You now should have this updated file automatically in your local svn folder.

Other than this, if this file does not get created on SVN update click, it means that this file is also deleted on the SVN server.

For this case, you will need to put the backup file in the same folder where it existed, then add your latest code, and then use **ADD** this new file for SVN versioning by clicking, then use **SVN Commit**.

New file in SVN local folder looks like

[image]

Also if still you can't commit, use the **Clean Up** function of SVN then do SVN Commit again.

Comment: Sorry it was Ram Problem....old files was less size .....new files was high only 2 gb RAm